# How can I create a UIImageView programmatically in NativeScript?

Tags: ios, swift, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am building a NativeScript-Vue application and I am trying to add an image to the large iOS navigation bar. An example can be found here:

[Add a button to large title navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741945/add-a-button-to-large-title-navigation-bar)

And, exactly like the linked question I need the image to only be visible when the large titles are enabled. Fortunately [there is a linked medium article](https://blog.uptech.team/how-to-build-resizing-image-in-navigation-bar-with-large-title-8ba2e8bcb840) which provides the solution.

However, I am having problems creating the UIImageView programmatically. Once I have managed to do this I think I will be able to convert the rest of the code.

I have tried the following:

1. Using the UIImageView constructor, but it required arguments in an unknown form
2. Creating a NS-Vue Image, but the `nativeView` property was undefined
3. Trying to hoist an already mounted image, but NativeScript threw errors

The NativeScript-Vue element that looks exactly what I need is as follows (however, I need to create the UIImageView with TypeScript instead):

```
<Image src="~/assets/images/users/eliottrobson.png" width="26" height="26"/>
```

This is the swift equivalent I am struggling to convert

```swift
private let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "image_name"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else struggles with this, the following works for me:

```
let image = UIImage.imageNamed("app/assets/images/users/eliottrobson.png");
let imageView = new UIImageView({ image: image });
```